# Unable to register ios bundle id used previously with free provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Before I've bought iOS developer licence I've been using free provisioning profile. Now, when I have active dev account, I'm unable to register App ID using Bundle ID used previously with free profile.

On the accounts tab I'm a member of two teams, with Agent role in one team, and Free role in the other team. The team with the Free role has one provisioning profile with the Bundle ID I'd like to use. Is there any was to remove this profile and those app ids so I can use it in my active dev account? The free profile is not visible on my profiles list on https://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Apple Developer Support, and it looks like than it is not possible to manage Bundle ID's created and used with Xcode free provisioning profiles. So if you face similar problem you have to ask support to remove those Bundle ID's.